# marginfix makes KOMA's \marginline flush towards the outside, rather than the inside?

Tags: koma-script, marginpar, double-sided

The [`marginfix`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix/) package seems to do something funny to KOMA's `\marginline` command. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[mpinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\newcommand\mnote[1]{\marginpar{\ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft} #1}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginline{Hereabouts is some text}
\mnote{Hereabouts is some text}
\lipsum[3-4]
\vspace{4\baselineskip}
\lipsum[5]
Notes here
\marginline{Hereabouts is some text}
\mnote{Hereabouts is some text}
\end{document}
```

Comment out `\usepackage{marginfix}` and things are flushed left on odd pages, right on even pages like I expected them to be. `marginfix` seems to reverse this behaviour (things are flushed away from the text block). Is this a bug?

The same thing happens in `scrarctcl`: marginfix makes things flush right instead of flush left.

What's weird is that if you define your own command to do more or less exactly what `\marginline` is supposed to do like so:

```
\newcommand\mnote[1]{\marginpar{\ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft} #1}}
```

Then things work as expected. What is going on?

[image: marginfix notes aligned wrong]

Looking at the image closely, the marginfix version isn't even aligned!

In case this is just a package version conflict thing, here's a `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2009/03/25 v3.03 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2009/06/08 v3.03b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2009/07/24 v3.04a KOMA-Script package (type area)
  lipsum.sty    2005/01/26 v1.0 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
marginfix.sty    2010/08/28 v0.9.1 Fix Margin Paragraphs
 ***********
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the `marginfix` package to me.  (I've reported [an issue](https://github.com/shicks/marginfix/issues/1).)

## Explanation

Several things are happening here at once.  First, as stated in the documentation (and can be seen with `\show\marginline`):

```
\marginline=\long macro:
#1->\marginpar [\raggedleft {#1}]{\raggedright #1}.
```

so there is nothing strange with KOMA so to speak.  The issue is that the `marginfix` package "switches" the meaning of the optional (for left margins) and regular (for right margins) arguments of `\marginpar`.  This happens even with the standard `article` class as can be verified by adding `\marginpar[left]{right}`.

Your custom solution uses only the single argument form of `\marginpar` and so is not affected by this bug.

The lack of alignment you see when you look closely is because your `\marginparwidth` is not wide enough to contain your first word "Hereabouts":

```
Overfull \hbox (7.3223pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--7
```

If you increase the width by issuing `\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5\marginparwidth}` for example, then you will see that things are indeed aligned.

One other issue you will see if you look *really* closely is that the way `marginfix` fixes overflowing notes spoils the alignments of the text baseline and the baseline of the note.  This is not a bug per se, but typographically undesirable nonetheless.  (Image from the first note higher on the page.)

[image: Mismatch of text and note baseline with marginfix package]